# Adding a constant to a Sigma notation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was asked to give the explicit formula of: $k_n = k_{n-1} + n$ with $k_1 = 4$. I came up with the following formula: $$k_n = 3 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k$$ 
I'm wondering if adding the constant to the Sigma notation is actually legal since I couldn't find this anywhere.

**EDIT: I am so sorry, the original sequence was $k_n = k_{n-1} + n$, not $k_n = k_{n-1} + 1$.**

Comment: The notation itself is OK, but the result is wrong if $k_n$ is indeed an arithmetic progression with common difference $1\,$ as posted.

Comment: Uh, why wouldn't it be legal?  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k$ is a real number isn't it?  $3$ is a real number, isn't it?  You are allowed to add real numbers together, aren't you?

Comment: @fleablood just curious since I couldn't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @dixv Could you explain why it's wrong? Seems right to me.

Comment: Find... what anywhere?  where did you search?  I've seen this all over the place.

Comment: @fleablood Adding a constant to the sigma notation. I couldn't find it, sorry.

Comment: Well consider $k_1 = 4$ but $3 + \sum_{k=1}^4 k = 3 + 10 = 13$.  $k_2 = 4+ 1 = 5$ but $3 + \sum{k=1}^5 = 3 + 15 = 18$.  And $k_3 = 5+ 1 = 6$ and $3 + \sum{k+1}^6 = 3+21 = 24$.  does that really seem right to you.  For one thing if $k_n = k_{n-1} + 1$ is increasing each term by $1$.  but $3 + \sum_{k=1}^n k$ is increasing each term by $n$.

Comment: @fleablood Check my edit. I had the original sequence formula wrong.

Comment: "EDIT: I am so sorry, the original sequence was... "  Um, then why don't you fix it? Why do you leave the error in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $3 + \sum_{k=1}^n k$ is fine.  Although in fact, there is a closed formula for this expression.

Just so you know, one common mistake is to write it as $$\sum_{k=1}^n k + 3.$$ I would generally avoid this because it's unclear whether it means $$\sum_{k=1}^n (k+3)$$ or $$(\sum_{k=1}^n k)+3,$$ and the two are different.

Answer (score 1):

You need not worry. $\sum_{k=1}^nk$ is just a number, and it is perfectly legal to add $3$ and that number. "$3+$" is not a part of the "sigma notation" at all.

Having said that, your formula for $k_n$ is not right. Did you know that $\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$? So, what you've written is $k_n=3+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

On the other hand, it is pretty obvious that it is just $k_n=3+n$. Try to prove it.

**Edit**: After you fixed your question, it seems that your solution (to the edited question) is fine.